# how to write test case for nested jsx returning function using jest and react testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, ts-jest

```
export default function App() {
  let arr = [{name:"a"},{name:"b"},{name:"c"},{name:"d"},{name:"e"},{name:"f"}]

  let **renderFn** = () => {
    return arr.map(a=>{
      return <div>{a.name}</div>
    })
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>{renderFn()}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How to test test nested function that returns a complete jsx and that function is invoked in the jsx itself.
I am unable to write test

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a nested function, instead move your function outside of the function App.
Declare it as a "First-class citizen", as a function that you export.

**Dependency injection** what ever your function needs should be passed as arguments.

Now you can test your function as a stand alone unit.

```
export function List({ list }) {
    return list.map(a => {
        return <div>{a.name}</div>
    })
}  
export default function App() {
    let arr = [{ name: "a" }, { name: "b" }, { name: "c" }, { name: "d" }, { name: "e" }, { name: "f" }]
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div><List list={arr} /></div>
        </div>
    );
}
```